# Javascript - Build an array based on image in dom

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to store a bunch of Image SRC attribute values in an array. I want to search the DOM for all `<img>` tags and grab the `SRC` attribute for each and put it into an array.

I know I can create an array like: `var imgSrc = new Array();`

But how do I add each SRC attribute to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imgSrc = [];
var imgEls = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0; i<imgEls.length; i++) {
    imgSrc.push(imgEls[i].getAttribute("src"));
}
```

... or, using jQuery:

```
var imgSrc = [];
$("img").each(function() {
    imgSrc.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method is how you add an item to an array in Javascript.

If you're using jQuery, this should get you what you're looking for:

```
var imgSrc = $("img").get().map(function(o, i) { 
    return $(o).attr("src"); 
});
```